# Installing cuda on ubuntu 16.10 - directory not found after installation

Tags: software-installation, cuda

I have installed cuda via a package manager. The installation seems to be successful:

```
$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation Built on Sun_Sep__4_22:14:01_CDT_2016 Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.44
```

And when I type `which nvcc` I get `/usr/bin/nvcc`. However, I think the cuda directory is not actually there:

```
$ ls -a /usr/local/bin
.   easy_install      f2py  gitsome      tensorboard   theano-nose 
xonsh.bat ..  easy_install-2.7  gh    gitsome.bat  theano-cache  xonsh
```

Is cuda actually installed, and if it is - where?

After running `dpkg --get-selections | grep cuda` I get the following output:

```
libcuda1-375                        install
libcudart8.0:amd64              install
nvidia-cuda-dev                 install
nvidia-cuda-doc                 install
nvidia-cuda-gdb                 install
nvidia-cuda-toolkit             install
```

Answer (score 2):

CUDA seems to be successfully installed.
It should get installed in `/usr/local/`.

Try checking with

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep cuda
```

This command shows the following result for successfully installed cuda7.5:
 [result of above command after installing cuda 7.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvpN1.png)

Comment: I updated my question with the result of dpkg --get-selections | grep cuda

Comment: did you try this [verify cuda install](http://xcat-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/gpu/nvidia/verify_cuda_install.html) ?

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: verifying  yields the expected output.

Comment: CUDA is installed in your system then. You can go ahead and use it.  Remember adding these variables to your .bashrc file:
    `export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH`
    
    `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still don't understand where cuda is installed and why I don't see its directory \: